# How to show only the first of my 3 div element when I load my page

Tags: jquery

I have 3 links each opening his own div element, the problem is that when I refresh my page each 3 are visible, and at load I want the first to be shown and then toggle with show and hide functions in jquery between each other

HTML

```
<a class="button" id="showdiv2">Div 2</a>
<a class="button" id="showdiv3">Div 3</a>
<a class="button" id="showdiv4">Div 4</a>
<div id="div2">2</div>
<div id="div3">3</div>
<div id="div4">4</div>
```

JS

```
        $('#showdiv2').click(function(){
            $('div[id^=div]').hide();
            $('#div2').show();
        });

        $('#showdiv3').click(function(){
            $('div[id^=div]').hide();
            $('#div3').show();
        });

        $('#showdiv4').click(function(){
            $('div[id^=div]').hide();
            $('#div4').show();
        });
```

Comment: add style="display:none" to the elements that you want to hide on page load.

Comment: and you'll probably have to use Prevent default in the click function because you're using a-tags. and I believe it's better to use .on("click", function() instead of .click(function() . see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9122078/difference-between-onclick-vs-click

Answer (score 3):

You can hide all but the first element in the set by using CSS. You can also DRY up your logic to use a single event handler by using common classes along with putting the selector to target in the `href` attribute. Try this:

```js
$('.button').click(function(e) { 
  e.preventDefault();
  $('.div').hide().removeClass('active')
    .filter($(this).attr('href')).show().addClass('active');
});
```

```css
.div ~ .div {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="button" href="#div2">Div 2</a>
<a class="button" href="#div3">Div 3</a>
<a class="button" href="#div4">Div 4</a>
<div class="div active" id="div2">2</div>
<div class="div" id="div3">3</div>
<div class="div" id="div4">4</div>
```

Comment: I've never used this before: ".div ~ .div" what does it do?

Comment: `~` is the general sibling selector: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors

Comment: Why do you use .click instead of .on?

Comment: Either is fine.

Comment: @Rory great DRY code, nice...but now I have one more thing to do, I wish to move class 'current' between div elements to know wich of them is in active state...

Comment: This is a nice solution and should be the accepted answer! @MarkoC, regarding a current-class: check jQuery toggleClass here: http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/

Comment: Actualy it didn't, I manage to add class current to element that got clicked, but class stays on the element where already has been added, sorry I am newbie so just strated to lear 3 months ago, sorry guys, I know this is like riding a bike for you but as I said I am just strating out...

Comment: Ah, ok. You can use `addClass()` and `removeClass()` to do it - I updated the answer for you

Answer (score 1):

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/afg8qn0j/

```
(function() {
    $('#div3').hide();
    $('#div4').hide();
 })();
```

This script block is loaded once the DOM is ready loaded. It hides your `#div3` and `#div4` initially.